# How do I debug a trivial vba function in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to debug a simple vba function that returns the array it is given but stops once it reaches an empty cell:

```
Function Test2(source() As Variant) As Collection
    Debug.Print "Hello"
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(source(i))
        Test2.Add source(i).Value
        Debug.Print source(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

When I pass an array to this function by writing, for example, `=Test2(A:A)` in a cell I get a `#VALUE!` error and see nothing printed to the Immediate Window.

I am less interested in finding out what is wrong with this function than how to use the tools to find the issue. Why is "TEST" not being printed to the Immediate Window, and, if there is a syntax error in my program, why does the compiler not set a breakpoint?

Comment: It's easiest to debug functions by calling them from a test Sub than from the worksheet.  It would help if you could describe exactly how you're calling it though.  What are you entering on the worksheet?

Comment: yes, call from a sub as Tim said. Also, you have a variable in the function declared with same name as the function(Test2). Not going to work

Comment: Also, i=i??? or really meant i=1

Comment: @TimWilliams I've added a description of how I'm calling this function. I'm not really sure how to use a Sub but I guess I can figure it out. So far I'm really disappointed with the quality of the tools available to vba programmers. Should I be using VS or something? If so, is there a guide for using VS with excel?

Comment: @MacroMarc I think I've addressed your comments, but it still doesn't work. I will try this "Sub" idea.

Comment: Same as other commentors, for every VBA function that is to be run from a sheet, I also create a sub or function that runs in the development environment, and where I can check every step and try to figure out what's wrong.  I will put debug.print statements at various places and check the output.  I will  step into a function to try to spot a problem.  It can be an arduous task and some times it takes a lot of figuring.  There may be no easy answer.

Comment: @K17 I think this answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: You write you want to return an array, but you keep editing your code  in different ways to instead return a collection. As I mentioned, a UDF cannot return a collection to a range.

Comment: @ExcelHero I think you're missing the point of my question. Read the title and last paragraph again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your function again, look down near the End Function statement.  In order to return a value from a function, you need to set the function name to the value to be returned.  So, if you want to return the value "1" (without the quotes) your last line before End Function should say ....

```
Test2 = 1
```

That is one possible reason for your #value error. There could be other reasons as well. but look at that first.

Comment: This is not the reason. It is possible for a function to return a collection to a calling procedure and such a function would not need to set the name of the function to the collection at the end, as you have described. THE PROBLEM here is that when a function is used as a UDF, it cannot return a collection to a range.

Answer (score 0):

Remove those brackets in source() variant. Simply Source.
You can use Range as data type instead of Variant, as your input is Range(A:A
Declare a new collection for adding values to the collection.
For iteration i used For each method.
Hope you can get an idea about your error from this below code

```
  Function Test2(source As Variant) As Collection
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim cell As Range
    Debug.Print "Hello"
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
     For Each cell In source
        Debug.Print cell.Value
        Debug.Print cell.Count
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                Exit For
            Else
             'Set itm = cell
                 c.Add cell.Value
             End If
     Next
    Set Test2 = c
End Function
```